# Binding options dropdown filtering with textbox value in Google App Maker

Tags: dropdownbox, google-app-maker

Good day to all,
I need your help to binding an dropdown in Google App Maker. 
I have 2 datasources, one for value and other for options and names. The problem is when I try to filter the dropbox with a textbox value.
[image: capture]

in TextBox's `onValueChange` I put this code but it does not work.

```javascript
var item = widget.parent.descendants;
app.datasources.Prycts_Cmpns.query.clearFilters();
app.models.FCTRSRCBDS.datasources.Prycts_Cmpns.query.filters.s_AliasCompany._contains=widget.value;
app.models.FCTRSRCBDS.datasources.Prycts_Cmpns.load();
```

the next code is the datasources options,value and names of the dropdown:
[image: capture]

How i can filter this dropdown with the filter?

Thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling, that

1. User enters some filter in TextBox
2. In `onValueChange` you call `clearFilters` what wipes user's input
3. You load `Prycts_Cmpns` datasource with no filters

So to fix this you can check that the TextBox is bound to `app.models.FCTRSRCBDS.datasources.Prycts_Cmpns.query.filters.s_AliasCompany._contains` and simplify `onValueChnage` event handler to this

```javascript
// at this point filter's value should be already set by binding
app.models.FCTRSRCBDS.datasources.Prycts_Cmpns.load();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @PavelShkleinik for your post correction and your clarifications regarding this topic. You've already seen that my English is not very good. I will try to improve it in future topics. I give the subject as solved. Do you think it is necessary to publish an answer with how everything was once it works ?. regards

Comment: If your final version significantly differs from this one then maybe it makes sense. Welcome!